# Smallest Palindromic Integer greater than X in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, palindrome

Question : The program must accept an integer N and a array of integers with length N and an integer X, The program should print the smallest palindrome formed by the integers of the array, which should be greater than the integer X

> Boundary Conditions:

```
1<=N<=10
1<=X<=10^8
Maximum Time Limit : 500 ms
```

My Code:

```
import sys
def Next_smallest_Palindrome(num,Num_List):
    numstr = str(num)
    for i in range(num+1,sys.maxsize):
        if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
            h=0
            for k in str(i):
                if int(k) in Num_List :
                    h+=1
            if h == len(str(i)):
                return i
a=int(input())
Num_List=sorted(list(map(int,input().split())),reverse = True)
Number=int(input())
print(Next_smallest_Palindrome(Number,Num_List))
```

My code works perfectly and it satisfy all the test cases. The logic i have used in my code is i am iterating over the numbers from `N+1` to `sys.maxsize` , checking whether they are palindromic or not if it is palindromic then should check whether the digits in the number present in the array of integers if it is true then it will return the number.

My question is , is there a better way of solving this instead of looping over the numbers like the `brute force approach`

> TestCases:

```
Input:
3
2 4 0
567
Output:
2002
```

```
Input:
4
1 2 3 4
12543
Output:
13131
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the output of the second example be 12421?

My code is a bit messy, but that's what I could come up with:

Note that you could also modify the code to sort the list L, which would produce faster results as you could use binary search to check if a digit is in L, use L[0] instead of min(L)... It would change the complexity from O(N.len(X)) to O(len(X).log(N)).

```
'''
The output should be greater than X, therefore 
number of digits of output >= number of digits of X

if number of digits of output = number of digits of X:

    most significant digit of ouput = most significant digit of X (Case 2.a)
    most significant digit of ouput > most significant digit of X (Case 2.b)
    
if this is not possible, then 
number of digits of output > number of digits of X:
    most significant digit of output = smallest integer in list different than 0

Also note: when we fill the first digit of the output,
we also fill the last digit with the same value
we are therefore guaranteed to obtain a palindrome

After filling out the first and last digits,
we fill the middle part recursively

if the output we already have is guaranteed to be bigger than X 
(left side of output bigger than that of X),
we fill the remaining digits in the middle with the minimum of L

When we have one digit remaining to fill,
we can either fill it equal to the digit in X (Case I), 
or greater than the digit in X (Case II)
'''

def smallestPalindromeGreaterThanX(L, X):
    
    def recursive(o, L, X, case):
        
        if not X: #X is empty
            return o + o[::-1]
        
        if len(X) == 1: #last digit to fill
            
            #Case I: right side of output > right side of X
            #digit left to fill of output can be equal to digit of X
            if not case:
                if int(X) in L: 
                    return o + int(X) + o[::-1]
                else:
                    bigger = min(i for i in L if i > int(X))
                    return o + str(bigger) + o[::-1]
            else:
                
                #Case II: right side of output <= right side of X  
                minList = [i for i in L if i > int(X)]
                
                if len(minList) > 0:
                    bigger = min(minList)
                    return o + str(bigger) + o[::-1]
                else:
                    return -1
                
        if int(X[0]) in L:
            return recursive(o + X[0], L, X[1:-1], int(o[::-1]) <= int(X[-len(o):]))
        else:
            #filled output with digit bigger than that of X
            #fill remaining with minimum of L
            bigger = min(i for i in L if i > int(X[0]))
            return o + str(bigger) + str(minimum)*(len(X)-2-2*len(o)) + str(bigger) + o
    
    minimum, index = min((minimum, index) for (index, minimum) in enumerate(L))
    maximum = max(L)
    
    #Case 1: a list only containing zero, therefore no solution
    if L[0] == 0 and len(L) == 1: return -1
    
    #Case 2: output will have same length as X
    mostSig = int(str(X)[0]) #most significant digit of X
    
    #Case 2.a: most significant digit of output = most significant digit of X
    
    minList = [int(i) for i in str(X)[1:-1]]
    if mostSig in L and len(minList) == 0 or (maximum >= min(minList)):
        #mostSig exists in L and it can produce an output greater than X
        
        result = -1

        result = recursive(str(mostSig), L, str(X)[1:-1], mostSig <= int(str(X)[-1]))
            
        if not result == -1: return int(result)
        
    #Case 2.b: most significant digit of output > most significant digit of X
    
    minList = [i for i in L if i > mostSig] 
    if not len(minList) == 0: #bigger than mostSig exists in L
        biggerThanMostSig = min(minList)
        return int(str(biggerThanMostSig) 
                   + str(minimum) * (len(str(X))-2) #fill with smallest digit, to have same length as X
                   + str(biggerThanMostSig))
        
    #Case 3: output will have length greater than that of X
    
    if not minimum == 0:
        smallestNonZero = minimum
    else:
        smallestNonZero = min(L[:index] + L[index+1:])
        
    return int(str(smallestNonZero) 
               + str(minimum) * (len(str(X))-1) #length greater than that of X by 1
               + str(smallestNonZero))
            
print(smallestPalindromeGreaterThanX([2,4,0], 567))
print(smallestPalindromeGreaterThanX([1,2,3,4], 12354))
```

Comment: Thank You for your post and thank for the mistakes i made in the test cases it was `12543 `and i wrote it as `12354` and `print(smallestPalindromeGreaterThanX([1,2,3,4], 12543))` while running this Expected Output : 13131 but got 21112 and the example test case i provided are just an example of best case scenarios but there are worst case scenarios

Comment: I apologize for the mistake, I corrected the error in case 2 andwill updated my answer. I've also written a script that chooses inputs at random and compares performance and results from your code and mine, and its at 100% equal results.

Comment: Did you edit your answer? @Hassan Kanj because i am still getting the same answer